# Link on image shows small artefact

Tags: html, anchor, image

I have a couple of links on some images. The code is very simply as follows:

```
<div id="socialnetworkbuttons">
    <a href="http://www.facebook.com/">
        <img src="images/facebook-button.png" alt="Facebook" />
    </a>
    <a href="https://twitter.com/" alt="Twitter">
        <img src="images/twitter-button.png" />
    </a>
</div>
```

I have a reset.css of:

```
html, body, div, span, applet, object, iframe,
h1, h2, h3, h4, h5, h6, p, blockquote, pre,
a, abbr, acronym, address, big, cite, code,
del, dfn, em, img, ins, kbd, q, s, samp,
small, strike, strong, sub, sup, tt, var,
b, u, i, center,
dl, dt, dd, ol, ul, li,
fieldset, form, label, legend,
table, caption, tbody, tfoot, thead, tr, th, td,
article, aside, canvas, details, embed, 
figure, figcaption, footer, header, hgroup, 
menu, nav, output, ruby, section, summary,
time, mark, audio, video {
    margin: 0;
    padding: 0;
    border: 0;
    font-size: 100%;
    font: inherit;
    vertical-align: baseline;
}

article, aside, details, figcaption, figure, 
footer, header, hgroup, menu, nav, section {
    display: block;
}
body {
    line-height: 1;
}
ol, ul {
    list-style: none;
}
blockquote, q {
    quotes: none;
}
blockquote:before, blockquote:after,
q:before, q:after {
    content: '';
    content: none;
}
table {
    border-collapse: collapse;
    border-spacing: 0;
}
```

And other css of:

```
#socialnetworkbuttons {
    display:inline-block;
    float:left;
}
```

The result looks like:

[image]

As you can see the is a small, purple ellipsis artefact at the bottom, which is a link that points to facebook. I'm sure I'm missong something terribly simple and obvious here, but how do I get rid?!

Comment: Maybe it's the images themselves that have the purple artefact?  Try opening them up in paint or something and examine the lower corners?

Comment: Isnt it just the space character in the a tag? Try setting text-decoration: none; on the a.

Comment: Certainly wasn't on the images, i made them myself! :P But yeah a simple extra space in the `a` tag. Pah!

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Looks like extra spaces in the A. Try:

```
<div id="socialnetworkbuttons"><a
     href="http://www.facebook.com/"><img
        src="images/facebook-button.png" alt="Facebook" /></a><a
     href="https://twitter.com/" alt="Twitter"><img
        src="images/twitter-button.png" /></a>
</div>
```

I have no ellipsis on Firefox or Chrome.

Comment: Always something stupid! This was it, can't believe it falls down on something so minor. Thanks anyway!